# Ruby, кэширование

Tags: ruby-on-rails, кэширование

Есть приложение на ruby. Меняю html код во вьюшке, но на странице изменения не отображаются. Кэш? Где и как его почистить? С ruby сталкиваюсь впервые.

Comment: @leol2, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Вы, наверное, имеете ввиду Рельсы. У неё (Рельсы) кеш по умолчанию хранится в tmp/cache.
Можно просто удалить каталог, можно выполнить:

```
rake tmp:cache:clear # Clears all files and directories in tmp/cache

rake tmp:clear # Clear session, cache, and socket files from tmp/
```

Кеш можно отключить в настройках.
Если у вас запущена рельса в режиме разработки, то кеш по умолчанию отключен, и проблему стоит искать в другом.

Comment: Пробовал. Не помогло... Папка tmp/cache пустая. И всё равно старый вариант, причем через раз. Иногда новый вариант, иногда старый. Странно.

Comment: Каким сервером запускаете? В каком режиме (среде)?

Comment: не знаю, в чем причина, но проблема решилась командой "service thin restart". После чего изменения во вьюшках начали сразу отображаться. Что бы это всё значило?..

Answer (score -2):

По умолчанию в Рельсах не происходит перезагрузка классов при каждом новом запросе. Вам надо добавить в `development.rb`:

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
```